# unable to get value of a variable inside a string : angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to get the value of a variable in following case :

**onclick="window.location.href = '#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}' "**

it just prints this to '#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}' instead to taking the value of message.pid

```
<div ng-repeat="message in userMessages track by $index">
            <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
                <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ message.a1id }}/picture?type=square">
                <h2>{{ message.mdata.a1n }}</h2>
                <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
                <button class="button button-small button-positive" href="#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}" onclick="window.location.href = '#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}' ">
                    View
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
```

**Can anyone tell me the mistake i am making ?**

Comment: You have put it as a string: `'#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}'`. Do something like `{{ '#/app/tmnl/' + message.pid }}` instead

Comment: Can you add your controller code ?

Answer (score 1):

You have put the `{{ }}` in a string, so angular won't evaluate that. Do something like this instead:

```
onclick="window.location.href = {{ '#/app/tmnl/' + message.pid }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**It worked when i replaced onclick to ng-click**

```
ng-click="window.location.href = '#/app/tmnl/{{ message.pid }}' "
```

Thanks everyone for other answers as well

Comment: You should not be using window.location.href. It will reload the entire page. If you want Single page application behavior this is not the right way.

Comment: What should i do then? a sref change ?

Comment: either ng-href or sref would be the correct way. Try using my answer in this way : <button><a ng-href="#/app/tmnl/message.pid">Button Text</a></button>